# Transparent Label on transparent form

Tags: c#, forms, label, transparent, backcolor

I googled a bit and tried some codes but I'm not able to draw a label without the border or backcolor.
So, I want to program a little timer, but I just want to see the numbers and not any kind of backtground.

In Java this is very easy, setUndecorated and setting the backcolor solved this in Java. Is there also a way in C#?

Comment: labels are transparent and borderless by default.

Comment: What's behind the label? Make sure to make the label a children of the control behind it, rather than the form, or the transparency won't be correct. If it overlaps with over than one element, you're pretty much screwed and should switch to WPF.

Comment: I just want to have a text without any kind of background. Something like a FPS-Counter (yes, this is a good example).
Behind the label is the transparent form.
My form is transparent and the backcolor of my label also, but it's just black... the whole label

Answer (score 0):

The only way answer i have is that you need to take a picture of the background and set the a Backgroundpicture of the lable to that. If you want to know how that works ill give you a code.

Comment: But this would cause maybe lags? Because I want to put the timer/countdown infront of a game.

Comment: So it won't lag if I use WPF?
Never worked with WPF, can I just make it transparent or what I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (assuming both your label and form have the same BackColor)...

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Make form invisible (except label text)
    this.TransparencyKey = this.BackColor;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

    // Optional, but you mentioned you had a border and backcolor on your label:
    this.label1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    this.label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want only a SEMI-transparent form, then you set the opacity to a percentage (.75 is 75%):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.label1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    this.Opacity = .75;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok thx guys :)
I used WPF, was easier after a bit research.

Here is my code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="CountDown.MainWindow"
    Title="CountDown" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Left="0" Top="0">
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0" Color="White"/>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="-2, -10"
        FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold"
        Text="90"
    />
</Grid>
```